# Regex match only if string contains what is specified but nothing else

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to implement a REGEX in perl that matches if the string contains anything I specify, but it must fail if the string contains anything else even if it contains my regex elements in addition.
For instance:

```
if ($string !~ m/[ACTG]{1,}/) {
  die "invalid sequence";
}
```

If I input `DQJ` as s sequence, the program dies. However, if I input `ACH` it doesn't since it contains at least one element from the regex pattern.

I would like the match to fail if the string contains anything other than A, C, T or G.

PS: I am unfamiliar with the nomenclature in this case, what would I call what is inside // in the regex statement?

Comment: You can omit `{1,}` without chaning the way the regex works. But what is your question?

Comment: @GuidoFlohr Thanks! I would like the program to die if the string contains anything other than ACTG.

Comment: use `=~` instead of `!~`, negate the character class `[^ACTG]`, remove the quantifier,  and eventually check if the string isn't empty.

Comment: Or use anchors ([see the manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)).

Comment: You can do with `die 'Invalid sequence' unless $string =~ /[ACTG]+/;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make sure every character is a valid character.

```perl
die if !/^[ACTG]*\z/;
```

Using the faster tr///:

```perl
die if tr/ACTG// != length($_);
```

Or you can make sure the string doesn't contain an invalid character.

```perl
die if /[^ACTG]/;
```

Using the faster tr///:

```perl
die if tr/ACTG//c;
```

Thanks to @DavidO for suggesting tr///.

Comment: Would you consider using transliteration with /c in this application? `tr/ACTG//c`

Comment: @DavidO. For sure. That would be be faster. Added.

Comment: The `\A` for the absolute beginning of the string would be better. If `/m` is somehow set (perhaps by the `use re '/m'`), there can be characters before the `^`. I've had to fix production code because someone followed some bad "best practice" advice by adding default regex flags. But, as you say, `tr` is even better for this job.

Comment: @brian d foy And you've just identified why that's not a best practice. Yeah, I could code defensively here, but "^" is far more recognized, doesn't add more leaning toothpicks, and adheres to the is-different-looks-different principle.

Comment: Note that all these solutions will allow the empty string, which may or may not be acceptable for the OP.

Comment: @pilcrow, The request was to fail if it contained characters other than ACGT. An empty stirng contains none of those. But fair to note it

Answer (score 3):

Use the `^` character to define the beginning of the string
and the `$` to define the end.

```
if ($string !~ /^[ACTG]*$/){die "invalid sequence";}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my match almost always fails if I implement it like this. It works only when Won't using ^ and $ match only if the sequence begins with A and ends with G, or something like that?

Comment: Note that this allow `AAAA␊`. Use `\z` to disallow that line feed.

Comment: @Alan There was a missing `*` (added)

Comment: @ikegami Works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: Along with ikegami's suggestion of `\z`, you should use `\A` for the absolute beginning on the string. Both the `^` and `$` have mutable meanings based on the state of the `/m` regex flag.